# xamarin - The type or namespace name 'Session' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: facebook, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using PCL xamarin.form having two projects android and IOS

I want to integrate facebook in project. I got source code to integrate facebook in project from below link:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31928/xamarin-forms-facebook-login-native-login-page-android

I installed Xamarin.Facebook.Android version - 4.7.0.1

I am getting error, you can see in below image

[image]

please suggest me how to solve this error

Thanks in advance

Comment: Documentation is outdated. API is different in the latest version of the library.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me which API I have to use and how to use that API.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find any Xamarin samples but I think you could use Android documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android Xamarin binding libraries will give you same API.

Comment: Maybe this one could be helpful https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Facebook

Comment: I tried this link - github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Facebook , it is opening facebook page in web browser/webview. I want app should use authentication directly from facebook app (install in mobile). i dont want to open facebook page in webview